# Source Engine - Strange factors in acceleration equation

Tags: c++, physics, source-engine

I was going through the [player movement code](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013/blob/master/mp/src/game/shared/gamemovement.cpp) for the [source engine](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013) when I stumbled upon the following function:

```
void CGameMovement::Accelerate( Vector& wishdir, float wishspeed, float accel )
    {
        int i;
        float addspeed, accelspeed, currentspeed;

        // This gets overridden because some games (CSPort) want to allow dead (observer) players
        // to be able to move around.
        if ( !CanAccelerate() )
            return;

        // See if we are changing direction a bit
        currentspeed = mv->m_vecVelocity.Dot(wishdir);

        // Reduce wishspeed by the amount of veer.
        addspeed = wishspeed - currentspeed;

        // If not going to add any speed, done.
        if (addspeed <= 0)
            return;

        // Determine amount of accleration.
        accelspeed = accel * gpGlobals->frametime * wishspeed * player->m_surfaceFriction;

        // Cap at addspeed
        if (accelspeed > addspeed)
            accelspeed = addspeed;

        // Adjust velocity.
        for (i=0 ; i<3 ; i++)
        {
            mv->m_vecVelocity[i] += accelspeed * wishdir[i];    
        }
    }
```

Although I do understand the concept of utilising the wishdir & wishspeed to calculate the velocity increment, I cannot figure out why they use the `wishspeed` and `m_surfaceFriction` in the calculation of `accelspeed`:

```
accelspeed = accel * gpGlobals->frametime * wishspeed * player->m_surfaceFriction;
```

I think it somehow compensates for the reduction in velocity due to friction [that was calculated earlier](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/source-sdk-2013/blob/master/mp/src/game/shared/gamemovement.cpp#L1612), but multiplying these two variables with `accel * gpGlobals->frametime` does not seem to make physical sense.

Would somebody be able to explain the thoughts behind this calculation and why this extra `wishspeed * player->m_surfaceFriction` factor is applied to the `accelspeed`?